# How to implement conditional branches in Azure Data Factory pipelines

Tags: azure-data-factory

I am implementing a pipeline to insert data updates from csv files to SQL DB. Plan is to first insert the data to temporary SQL table for validation and transformation, and then move processed data to actual SQL table. I would like to branch the pipeline execution depending on the validation result. If data is OK, it will be inserted to target SQL table. If there are fatal fails, insertion activity should be skipped.

Tried to find instructions / guidance but no success so far. Any ideas if pipeline activity supports conditional execution, e.g. based on some properties in input dataset?

Comment: Actually i'm also searching for the same Solution here,how to conditionally make the Pipeline to be execute.

Answer (score 2):

It is possible now with Azure Data Factory ver 2.

Post execution our downstream activities can now be dependent on four possible outcomes as standard.
 - On success 
 - On failure 
 - On completion 
 - On skip
Also, custom ‘if’ conditions will be available for branching based expressions.

Refer below links for more detail:-

https://www.purplefrogsystems.com/paul/2017/09/whats-new-in-azure-data-factory-version-2-adfv2/

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/data-factory/tutorial-control-flow

Answer (score 0):

The short answer is **no**.

I think its worth pointing out that ADF is just an orchestration tool to invoke other services. The current version can't do what you want because it does not have any of its own compute. Its not an SSIS data flow engine.

If you want this behaviour you'll need to code it into the SQL DB stored procedures with flags etc on the processed datasets.

Then maybe have some boiler plate code with a parameters that are passed from ADF to perform either the insert or update or divert operation.

Handy link for called stored procedure with params from ADF: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/data-factory/data-factory-stored-proc-activity

Hope this helps.